# Store method return value in JSP page as variable

Tags: java, jsp

If I have a method like this in *UserController*:

```
@GetMapping("/username")
@ResponseBody
public String username(Principal principal) {

    return principal.getName();
}
```

then is there a way to store the username in the JSP page as variable? Something like

```
<%  
        String username = request.getParameter("/username");
%>
```

(obviously this isn't working)
I'm new to JSP and I don't know how to do it

Comment: There are a number of objects accessible in jsps. One of them is request. There is also one for session https://www.javatpoint.com/session-implicit-object. You could create a session and save it there.

Comment: In this case, it would be: `String username = request.getRemoteUser();`